# Дописать данные в БД один ко многим Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Изучаю EF, столкнулся с некой проблемой работы с БД один ко многим. Например, у меня есть две таблицы:

1-я: Users

2-я: Roles

В таблице роли должно быть, например, две роли "администратор" и "супер администратор", Id которых должны присваиваться нужным полям в таблице Users. Но когда я хочу троим пользователям задать уже существующую роль, получается, что роль "администратор" создаётся заново и юзеру присваивается id новой роли. Как с этим быть и работать?

Users

```
public class Users
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Login { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public int? RoleId { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

Roles

```
public class Role
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Users> UserAll { get; set; }

    public Role()
    {
        UserAll = new List<Users>();
    }
}
```

Выполнение самой записи

```
using (AppContext db = new AppContext())
{
    var role1 = new Role { Name = "Administrator" };
    var user1 = new Users { Login = "admin", Password = "1231", Role = role1, Email = "test@gmail.com", FirstName = "null", LastName = "null"};
    db.Users.AddRange(new List<Users>{user1});
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

---

Единственное до чего додумался, это заранее скачивать данные из таблицы Role, затем сравнивать с тем, что вводит пользователь и только потом присваивать с выбранным id.

Comment: Верно, так и нужно делать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этой строкой вы создаёте **новую** роль:

```
var role1 = new Role { Name = "Administrator" };
```

Естественно, она потом добавляется в БД.

Нужно получить уже существующую роль из БД:

```
var role = db.Roles.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Name == "Administrator");
if (role == null)
{
    // обработка ошибки или создание роли
};
```

---

Чтобы не допустить случайного создания новой роли с тем же именем, следует наложить ограничение уникальности на колонку Role.Name. В разных версих EF это делается по-разному.

---

Класс `Users` содержит информацию об одном человек, поэтому название должно быть в единственном числе: `User`.

Не храните в БД пароли в чистом виде. Храните их хэши, причём обязательно с солью.

Comment: Большое спасибо за подсказку, я для себя ожидал гораздо больше кода по проверке запрашиваеммых данных. Подскажите пожалуйста что значит "... Храните их хэши, причём обязательно с солью.", а именно что вы называете солью ? 
Данный явный вид только для тестов. Спасибо за подсказку огромное

Comment: @Ethernets - если владеете английским, рекомендую эту статью: [Adding Salt to Hashing: A Better Way to Store Passwords](https://auth0.com/blog/adding-salt-to-hashing-a-better-way-to-store-passwords/). Можете создать новую тему с этим вопросом.

Comment: Принято, большое спасибо. Хорошего вечера, чуть позже если будет что-то не ясно создам обязательно