# В модель EF Core не заносится вся информация с бд

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

У меня есть три модели: User, UserData, UserRoles.

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public UserRoles Role { get; set; }
    public UserData Data { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class UserRoles
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class UserData
{
    //[Column("UserDataId")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public float DigitalMoney { get; set; }

    //public int UserId { get; set; }
    //public User User { get; set; }
}
```

И есть ApplicationDbContext, в нём и хранится вся БД (EF Core 5)

```
public class ApplicationDbContex : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContex(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserRoles> Roles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserData> Datas { get; set; }
}
```

Так достаю с БД определенного пользователя по userName:

```
var result = _db.Users.Include(c => c.Data).Include(c => c.Role).SingleOrDefault(s => s.UserName == username);
```

В БД есть готовый User, но беда в том, что его поля Data и Role пусты (null), что с этим можно сделать?

*(.Net 5, MySql)*

Comment: Всё должно работать. Покажите код, как заносите данные в БД.

Comment: Покажите код вставки. Что-то наподобие: `_db.Users.Add(...`

Comment: И уточните: вы действительно используете MySql или всё же Sql Server (потому что их постоянно путают! Я уже устал от этого...)

Comment: Нет, я добавляю юзеров сразу в БД через спец сайт, но щас попробую через код

Comment: Ну, хорошо, покажите, как выглядят данные в БД. Например, скриншоты, где видно все три таблицы с парой строк в каждой. Чтобы можно было сравнить ключи.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/VDClggpqKk5l 
https://prnt.sc/ldbVAr9jwrQV
https://prnt.sc/3Crn_Vy6CKPX

Да, MySql

Comment: https://pastebin.com/hzUj77zp - вот так я проверял. Данные вывелись. Правда, я использовал то, что под рукой: SqlServer и EF Core 6. Консольное приложение.

Comment: Щас я попробую сделать что-то подобное

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Спасибо огромное, я не знаю как, но оно работает, я очень вам благодарен, я новичёк на этом форуме, тут есть кнопка какой-то благодарности?

Comment: На ваших скриншотах не видно _данные_. Я хотел что-то наподобие https://i.imgur.com/6MXt3vs.png.

Comment: Ещё замечание: не используйте для хранения денег вещественные типы `float` и `double`. Только `decimal`.

Comment: Напишите ответ сами, что проблема была в неправильно вставленных данных. И потом примите его.

Comment: Вот данные https://prnt.sc/HYuU7ezrIuyg https://prnt.sc/GZRFtB9Tg0YO https://prnt.sc/Dj65oDLJD7jo

Comment: Спасибо за decimal, через пару минут напишу в чём было дело, еще раз огромное спасибо

Comment: Я показал код именно для проверки работоспособности вставки. В реальном коде роли должны предварительно получаться из БД и назначаться уже готовые юзерам. Примерно как здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1421370/184217

Comment: Да, я примерно понимаю как оно работает теперь, но всё еще сложно в понимании с EF Core

Answer (score -1):

```
public class User
{
    
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Role))]
    public Int32? IdRole { get; set; }
    public virtual UserRoles Role { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Data))]
    public Int32? IdUserData{ get; set;}
    public virtual UserData Data { get; set; }
}

public class UserRoles
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey(nameof(User))]
    public Int32? IdUser { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    

}

public class UserData
{
    //[Column("UserDataId")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public float DigitalMoney { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey(nameof(User))]
    public Int32? IdUser { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Поля должны быть помеченные ключевым словом `virtual`
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/relationships

Comment: Судя по выбранным меткам, Вы используете asp.net core, для работы с пользователем можно использовать asp.net core identity. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio   https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/16.1.php

Comment: Не совсем, я более использую Blazor, но и AspNet до кучи, но оно всё равно не работает

Comment: Дополнил немного кода, как я достаю из бд юзера(даже через include не помогает)

Comment: @zomgra, а у вас в БД созданы FK (внешние ключи) в соответствующих таблицах?

Comment: @Konst Не знаю, как я могу это проверить?

Comment: Как правильно подметил @Konst ключи не созданы, zomgra, Вам нужно создать миграцию и обновить БД https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=vs

Comment: У меня есть предположения что дело в Include, и взятие User`a с бд

Comment: Миграция у меня есть, но подозреваю что и с ней всё не так

Comment: @zomgra ну после обновления БД проверьте вручную созданные ключи или нет.

Comment: Решил я удалить и создать миграцию заново, как она перестала создаваться с ошибкой:
Get-Package : Project '/Users/nikitaserduk/Projects/TestAuth2/TestAuth2.csproj' is not found.
At /Users/nikitaserduk/.nuget/packages/entityframework/5.0.0/tools/EntityFramework.psm1:611 char:16
+     $package = Get-Package -ProjectName $project.FullName | ?{ $_.Id  ...

Comment: Перезапустил VS и вот что(Tools есть 5.0.17 версии):
add-migratiom : The term 'add-migratiom' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: Читайте ошибку, там уже ответ, нет такой команды "add-migratiom", есть команда "add-migration"

Comment: @User Прошу прощения, даже не подумал о том, что бы посмотреть на что я написал, спасибо

Comment: Cделал всё как и предлагали, даже вроде FK есть в коде, но всё еще модели в модель

Comment: И БД обновил миграцией? Ключи физически создал?

Comment: Да, миграцию создал, ключи создались сами(Primary, IX_Users_IdRole, IX_Users_IdUserData)
(Миграцию заново создал)

Comment: Автор пишет, что использует EF Core. Вы даёте ссылку на документацию EF 6. Это сильно разные фреймворки.

Comment: Да, у меня EF Core 5.0.0, но ссылка вроде как тоже на EF Core

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да, мой косяк, загуглил и не обратил внимание на конкретную версию